# Matching "beginning-of-line" using libc++ regex library (C++11)

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, clang, libc++

I would like to match all lines that start with a given word, say iheap. If I am not mistaken the regular expression (in ECMAScript syntax) `"^iheap.*"` should do the trick. However, when I tested this in C++11 using libc++'s regex library, only the first line is matched. So `"^..."` seems to only match beginning-of-input instead of beginning-of-line.

Here is an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        regex rx("^iheap.*");
        string s = "iheap says hello.\niheap says hello again.\n";
        cout << s << regex_replace(s, rx, "IHEAP");
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
iheap says hello.
iheap says hello again.
IHEAP
iheap says hello again.
```

Is this a bug of libc++ or am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

*Note*: I am using Mac OS X Mountain Lion and Apple LLVM Compiler 4.0 (basically a snapshot of clang 3.1 SVN).

Comment: just stumbled on this problem ... fyi, boost::regex (in EMCAScript mode) matches beginning-of-line, ie your regex would work.

Comment: Hrmm, only slightly related, but `$` doesn't match against `\r\n` in VS2013 -- it takes `\s*$` or similar to match...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've looked over all of the relevant standards, and as far as I can tell, ^ matches only the beginning of the string, and not a newline, unless the engine is in *multiline* mode.  The default engine is [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)  The engine is not in multiline mode by default, and I see no way to put it into multiline mode using the std C++ interface.

All that being said, if someone can point me towards normative text that says differently, I'll consider this a bug report and do my best to fix it.

Comment: Just for a giggle, try this: `(?m)^iheap.*`.  ECMA-262 doesn't specify inline modifiers, but `libc++` might support them anyway.  This wouldn't be the only ECMAScript regex implementation to unilaterally add support for features not covered in the spec.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Just tried it, an exception is throwed. Unfortunately it seems they are not supporting that extension.

Comment: Hello Howard. I also could not find a normative text that settles the question, but I think I have a justification strong enough to imply that the default mode should be multiline. There is the `std::regex_constants::match_not_bol` flag whose function is to make sure that the `"^"` assertion does not match beginning of the input. With that flag in the multiline mode; the `"^"` assertion will match all the lines except the first line. In the single-line mode, that flag will make the `"^"` assertion non-functional, which does not make sense to me.

Comment: I found two unofficial reference websites that support my interpretation. Check out the explanation of the `"^"` assertion in [this website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/regex/ECMAScript/) and the explanation of the `match_not_bol` flag in [this website](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_flag_type). I know these are not normative texts, but they present some evidence to the fact that many people expect this multiline behavior as the default. Note that we have the same issue with the `"$"` assertion (and there is a corresponding flag `match_not_eol`).

Comment: I will look into this.  Thanks for your investigation.

Comment: the standard says nothing about this, but the 2 other working implementations i know about (boost::regex and visual studio 2012) matches ^ and $ with newlines.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been listed at 2343 of http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-toc.html .